# How to exclude localhost in Chrome extension Tab Suspender

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

To use ipython notebook in chrome. I have to exclude `localhost` from [Tab Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-suspender/fiabciakcmgepblmdkmemdbbkilneeeh?hl=en). How to do this? I have tried adding `localhost` but it doesn' t work.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to another extension [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg), which offers easy adding to whitelist shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Since 0.4.7 version, you can use `*localhost*` to exclude `localhost`.